# Change "From" Email Address on Email Template

Tags: email

Our users have two email addresses that they use and based on the customer, they would like to have Salesforce change the "FROM/RETURN" email address when sending emails. Is this possible to do on a Template level, meaning if one template is selected use email A and likewise if another is selected use email B? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have definable criteria, you can create two separate e-mail templates and then go to Setup-->Build-->Create-->Workflow&Approvals-->Workflow Rules and create a separate rule to capture the condition that would trigger the use of a specific template. When you get to Step 2 (Configure Workflow Rule), use the formula option under Rule Criteria to provide the criteria that you need, then in Step 3 you can select the template you want to use.